# Can C++0x still explicitly allocate with global operator new?

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Explicitly-defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions) states:

> A type can be made impossible to allocate with operator new:
>
> ```
> struct NonNewable {
>     void *operator new(std::size_t) = delete;
> };
> ```
>
> An object of this type can only ever be allocated as a stack object or as a member of another type. It cannot be directly heap-allocated without non-portable trickery. (Since placement new is the only way to call a constructor on user-allocated memory and this use has been forbidden as above, the object cannot be properly constructed.)

Deleting operator new is similar to making it private in current C++, but isn't explicitly using global operator new, which avoids class-specific lookup, still valid C++0x?

```
NonNewable *p = ::new NonNewable();
// neither non-portable nor trickery, though perhaps not widely known
```

Have I missed something in the draft?

---

To be clear, this is valid C++03 and [works fine](http://codepad.org/98y624e3):

```
struct NonNewable {
private:
  void *operator new(std::size_t);  // not defined
};

int main() {
  // ignore the leaks, it's just an example

  void *mem = operator new(sizeof(NonNewable));
  NonNewable *p = ::new(mem) NonNewable();

  p = ::new NonNewable();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI if you're checking: the quoted text has been deleted from the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are right and wikipedia is wrong.  The C++0x draft standard describes "deleted functions" (8.4p10) as functions which may not be used in any way (or else the program is ill-formed).  They play no part in scope or name lookup different from normal functions.  And the relevant paragraphs concerning new expressions have remained the same:

> [5.3.4p8]  A new-expression obtains storage for the object by calling an allocation function (3.7.4.1). ...
>
> [5.3.4p9] If the new-expression begins with a unary :: operator, the allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.  Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type T or array thereof, the allocation function's name is looked up in the scope of T.  If this lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a class type, the allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.

So yes, the expression `::new NonNewable` [or `::new(mem) NonNewable`] would choose an overload of `::operator new`, ignoring the function `NonNewable::operator new`, and would not make the program ill-formed.